# Javascript Arrays merging using indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to merge 2 javascript arrays using indexes.

let's say I have array `A` with

```
A[0] = 1;
A[1] = 9;
...
A[5] = 12;
```

and array `B` with:

```
B[0 ... 5] = garbage, unused;
B[6] = 23;
B[7] = 99;
B[8] = 31;
...
B[10] = 990;
```

I want to merge `A` with `B` to do:

```
merged[0] = 1;
merged[1] = 9;
..
merged[5] = 12;
merged[6] = 23;
...
merged[10] = 999;
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 10):

Use a combination of [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
var C = A.concat(B.slice(6));
```

`concat` joins together two arrays and returns the result, while `slice` creates a copy of a portion of an array, where you specify the starting [and ending] index[es] of that portion.

http://jsfiddle.net/xaERK/